# Extract type of static member class object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have this `inteface` and `class`:

```
interface MyInterface {
  prop1: boolean;
  prop2: string
}

class MyClass {
  static readonly Something: MyInterface;
  static readonly AnotherThing: MyInterface;
}
```

Would it be possible to define a variable that needs to be a static member of `MyClass` and an specific `prop` of `MyInterface`

```
const myProp2: Some_Type_with_prop2 = MyClass.Something.prop2 // valid
const myProp2: Some_Type_with_prop2 = MyClass.AnotherThing.prop2 // valid
const myProp1: Some_Type_with_prop1 = MyClass.Something.prop2 // invalid
const myProp1: Some_Type_with_prop1 = MyClass.AnotherThing.prop2 // invalid
const myProp2_2: Some_Type_with_prop2 = 'hello' // invalid
```

In any case. The `Something` and `AnotherThing` part is what I need to get dynamically like:

```
<Myclass,'prop2'> ->  MyClass.xxxxx.prop2
```

Comment: A suggestion - you may make your interface properties optional using `?`

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem though.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
interface MyInterface {
    prop1: boolean;
    prop2: string;
}

class MyClass {
  static readonly something: MyInterface;
  static readonly anotherThing: MyInterface;
}

type PropOne = typeof MyClass["something"]["prop1"];
type PropTwo = typeof MyClass["something"]["prop2"];

const myProp2: PropTwo = MyClass.something.prop2; // valid
const myProp1: PropOne = MyClass.something.prop2; // invalid
const myProp2_2: PropTwo = 'hello'; // invalid
```

And if you want something more generic you can define the following type:

```
type SubPropType<T, K extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K]> = T[K][K2];
```

And use it as follows:

```
type PropOne = SubPropType<typeof MyClass, "something", "prop1">;
type PropTwo = SubPropType<typeof MyClass, "something", "prop2">;
```

You don't need to create the type aliases if you don't wont to. The types can be used in line:

```
const myProp2: SubPropType<typeof MyClass, "something", "prop1"> = MyClass.something.prop2; // valid
const myProp1: SubPropType<typeof MyClass, "something", "prop2"> = MyClass.something.prop2; // invalid
const myProp2_2: SubPropType<typeof MyClass, "something", "prop2"> = 'hello'; // invalid
```

I don't think it is possible to get the first level prop dynamically using only the name of the sub-prop.

Comment: That will work but it doesn't escales I have to create a new type every time a new static method is added. Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: You don't have to create it, it's just looks nicer, you can use the type query itself: `let o:  typeof MyClass["something"]["prop2"];`

Comment: I have updated the answer if you play with mapped types and conditional types you might be able to come up with something that can handle a not pre-defined number of sub-properties but I don't think it is possible to do much better than that.

Comment: I meant the `"something"` part is always hard code and when a new static member of `MyClass` is added it can be used mapping it: I Suppose it is not possible because it is a class and not an `enum`? (at least I wasn't able to find it). I have added a second example to clarify that the `Something` `AnotherThing` should be inferred and not hard coded.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a type indexor

```
const myProp2: MyInterface['prop2'] = MyClass.Something.prop2 // valid 
const myProp1: MyInterface['prop1'] = MyClass.Something.prop2 // invalid 
const myProp2_2: MyInterface['prop2'] = 'hello' // invalid
```

Comment: That does not limit the const to static methods of `MyClass` :(